# Accessing the column names from the string containing a JSON in java

Tags: java, json, hive-query

I have a string in java

```
String val = "{"column":[{"name":"id,"type":"int"},{"name":"empname","type":"string"}], "database":"test","table":"sample"}"
```

How do I retrieve only the column name
My result must be a string containing the column names delimited by tabspace i.e

Expected Output

```
id      empname
```

Comment: your json is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid (it seems that `"`is missing after `id` among other issues), but assuming you'd have a similarly structured valid one, you could use lib [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) as stated in accepted answer of this question: [How to parse JSON in Java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

In your case, you need following code:

```
import org.json.*;

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(val); 
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("column");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
    ......
}
```